# I can't seem to get this jQuery animation to be able to repeat more than three times

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

```
$("#name").change(function() {
        sav$("#saveMenu").click(function() {
        $("#shadow").finish()
        $("#slideInLeft").finish();
        $("#slideInLeft").show();
        $("#slideInLeft").children().fadeIn();
        $("#slideInLeft").animate({width: '240px'});
        $("#shadow").show();
        $("#shadow").animate({opacity: ".8"})
        $("#shadow").click(function() {
            $("#slideInLeft").children().fadeOut()
            $("#slideInLeft").animate({width: '0px'}, function() {
                $("#slideInLeft").hide();
                $("#shadow").animate({opacity: "0"}, function() {$("#shadow").hide()});
            });
        });
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4rvkqvo6/

When I run this, by triggering a click, it seems to work three times, but then it stops working. I can't figure out how to make this work.

Comment: your code is a working code.

Comment: Odd. It doesn't work on my end. Maybe a runtime error.

Comment: it's working here, I'm using google chrome.

Comment: add this to #filemenu in the css: 
-webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;

Comment: working over here too

Comment: Confirmed working in Safari 9.0